# SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments crash on IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

it's really a strange problem

when my app start I will make [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]

when I run my app on iPad simulator 5.0, it just crash on [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]

[image]

but it work on iPad simulator 4.3

did I miss something to do before I do [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]?

update:

I make [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments at the beginning

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

  // Override point for customization after app launch.

       [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
```

and it crash immediately..

but I do the same thing in a new Project ,it doesn't crash..

is there something wrong with my project setting??

Comment: Show us your code around the `canMakePayments` call.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!!

it's language problem....

My product name is not english

after I change it to english ,every thing works on iOS 5